# Stack Exchange API page should have proper capitalization

Tags: feature-request, api, capitalization

On the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) page, it says

> [image: Get Started With Our API]

When it’s rendered, it’s all lowercase. However, it’s really

> Get Started With Our API

So could the CSS be changed from

```
.introtext{
  color: #3a6da6;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  clear: both;
  margin:0 auto 20px
}
```

To

```
.introtext{
  color: #3a6da6;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin:0 auto 20px
}
```

So that it looks like this
[image]
<sub>(Yes, I edited the style)</sub>

Comment: @Hack why the removal of the new image?

Comment: It's there... where do u see it. I only added URL

Comment: I think my edit went in queue first then yours. It was a conflict. Also, I was in the middle of drafting my answer.

Comment: Something about the title of this question makes me sad.

Comment: @NathanTuggy what is it?

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy: "Stackexchange [sic]" (It's two words and both should be capitalized.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy ummm What?

Comment: Title Case looks horrible there

Comment: @random That isn’t even normal book-title case: she capitalized *with*.

Comment: Stack Exchange is two words

Answer (score 8):

It renders lowercase because of the CSS property "text-transform: lowercase;" used on the .introtext class

Here is the CSS code

```
.introtext {
    color: #3a6da6;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

I think (this is just my assumption - Only SE team can tell the real reason) that's what developer (plus the UI/UX team) decided to go for. And, also it could very well fall [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) category.